# hugging face, whisper model large v2, outputs weird character after training

Tags: speech-recognition, huggingface-transformers, openai-whisper, huggingface-trainer

I have been fine-tuning whisper on JASMIN CGN which is a Dutch dataset. I have preprocessed it locally. The original encoding for the sentences there is latin_1, but I made sure to convert each one of them to utf_8.v Then I followed the steps in that HF tutorial for Whisper fine-tuning, and this is the output I get (I use jiwer to get side-by-side sentence comparisons):

```
sentence 80

REF: \*\*\*\* maar voor de idianen was het niet zo voor hun moest een jongend een goede jager en krijger worden end een meisje moet goed kunnen koken en dat leerden ze niet op school de vader de grootvaders en de ooms vertelden de kleine jongens alles ik kan \*\*\* niet de oorlog ze toonden hem hoe je een spoor van de dier volgt end hoe je een boog opspant

HYP: �ien maar voor de idianen was het niet zo voor hen moest een jongent een goede jager en krijger worden en een meisje moet goed kunnen koken en dat leerden ze niet op school de vader de grootvaders en de ooms vertelden de kleine jongens alles ik kan het niet de oorlog ze toonden hem hoe je het spoor van de dier volgt en toe je een boog opspant 


sentence 76

REF: \* pakketten zijn uh in verschillende soorten en maten je kunt zo allerlei dingen gebruiken je kunt ze voor allerlei dingen gebruiken een een gemeente is uh een stad of een dorp of een paar klein dorpen samen ambtenaren van de gemeente cuntroleren of alle kinderen naar school gaan de gemeente houdt de stad schoon en zorgt v voor goede uhm straten en fietspaden ook zorgt de gemeente voor de bomen en de parken het is ook belangrijk dat de v

HYP: � pakketten zijn ã©ã©n \*\* verschillende soorten en maten je kunt ze allerlei dingen gebruiken je kunt ze voor allerlei dingen gebruiken een een gemeente is uh een stad of een dorp of een paar klein dorpen samen ambtenaren van de gemeente controleren of alle kinderen naar school gaan de gemeente houdt de stad schoon en zorgt v voor goede uhm straten en fietspaden ook zorgt de gemeente voor de bomen en de parken het is ook belangrijk dat de v
```

Does anyone know what the "?" is? I checked my test file with the whisper model without training it and I don't get any question marks there so I think there is something up with the training.

Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured out when the replacement character is there. During the evaluation pipeline we can specify the language of the model. When you specify that "language":"<|nl|>", there is no longer the replacement character! That way the whisper processor knows the language and doesn’t get confused by the utf8 codes that it doesn’t have in English. (At least that’s what I think)

Comment: Super interesting, Golshid, thank you for flagging this. I had a look through your notebooks and  couldn't find anything else that would account for it. I wonder if the replacement characters are a form of hallucination?

Answer (score 0):

The character `�` is the [Unicode replacement character](https://unicodeplus.com/U+FFFD) - which is used when a character cannot be encoded in the target encoding.

What I *think* has happened here is that it has happened during the encoding conversation from Latin-1 to UTF-8.

It might be worth calculating how many occurrences are in your REF sentences to see if it's a widespread problem.

Comment: If this was the problem, shouldn't testing the Whisper model without training also include this character? Because it doesn't. Just the model I fine tuned gives this output!

It is quite widespread, out of 10, 9 include this character.

Comment: The transcriptions are .ort files and in order for me to be able to work with them and put them in a csv, I converted them to .txt file, in this process they have been converted to UTF-8. I have checked the .txt files with `hexdump -C` but I don't see anything wrong with the convertions.

Comment: Ah, I see. So the fine-tuned Whisper sentences - `HYP` in this example, contain the Unicode replacement characters, but the original Whisper sentences, prior to fine-tuning, do not. Therefore, they have been introduced through the fine-tuning process. 

Are you able to link to the HF fine-tuning tutorial and I will have a look at that and see if there's anything in there which could be causing the prediction of Unicode replacement characters?

Comment: Here is the [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aez-pPsPc73u1b6EhdK-sgmtHfpY9yEy?usp=sharing) to the notebook I made and my project and here is the [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/sanchit-gandhi/notebooks/blob/main/fine_tune_whisper.ipynb) notebook I used. Thanks for your help, @Kathy.